# How can i specify the quality of the photo in Flutter MultiImagePicker?

Tags: image, flutter, frontend, imagepicker

I need to upload an amount of photos and send these photos to the database. Due to the high quality of the photo, it takes a fair amount of time to complete and upload each photo. I don't need a very high quality photo so I need to compress the photo. What the best solution to do that if i use the class Flutter MultiImagePicker ?

```
List<Asset> pickedImagesList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(maxImages: 25, enableCamera: false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package already propose a few options to compress an `Asset` object.

```dart
List<Asset> pickedImagesList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(maxImages: 25, enableCamera: false);
for (Asset asset in pickedImagesList) {
   ByteData assetData = await asset.getThumbByteData(
      width: // desired width,
      height: // desired height,
      quality: //desired quality,
   );
   // Send assetData to your database
}
```

**EDIT**

I think this could work to keep your aspect ratio:

```dart
double getAspectRatio(double originalSize, double desiredSize) => desiredSize / originalSize;

final aspectRatio = getAspectRatio(asset.originalWidth, imageDesiredWidth);
ByteData assetData = await asset.getThumbByteData(
   width: (asset.originalWidth * aspectRatio).round(),
   height: (asset.originalHeight * aspectRatio).round(),
   quality: //desired quality,
);
```

Comment: Hello again. Maybe you know how to change image width and height and image aspect ratio stayed the same ?

Comment: I've edited my answers with an example for aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the original width and height without any manipulate
use

```
getByteData(quality: 80)
```

instead

```
getThumbByteData(quality: 80)
```